# Esri .prj file in CAD

Tags: coordinate-system, cad, prj

How do I open an image with an Esri .prj file in ProdgeCAD and have it align correctly with my data?

Comment: images not supported but shape2dwg is https://www.progesoft.com/products/progecad-professional/shp2dwg